# Test fails due to NoSuchElementError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-mobile, protractor

I have a test that fails some times. I would very much like it to pass every time.
It's a page that shows an open layers map with some bubbles with numbers. 
When the page opens we click a status filter and then expect a certain number to be shown in one of the bubbles.

The error is:
NoSuchElementError: no such element.

It doesn't say which element it can't find. 
When I look at the screenshot I can see it never clicked the filter checkbox. Or at least doesn't show it in the screenshot. (When the test passes it shows the clicked checkbox)

Here is the test code:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;

});

function waitForMap(){
    ptor.wait(function () {
        return element(by.css('label[for="checkbox-status-all"]')).isPresent();
    }, 5000);

}

it('should click checkbox and expect 30 to be shown in bubble', function () {
    browser.get(ptor.params.testurl).then(function () {
        waitForMap();
        element(by.css('label[for="checkbox-status-b0"]')).click();
        var bedscount = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('marker_10'));
        expect(bedscount.getInnerHtml()).toEqual('<span>30</span>');
    });
});
```

Comment: i am not sure with that, maybe you have to wait for the click promise to be solved e.g.: element(by.css('label[for="checkbox-status-b0"]')).click().then(function() { ... get bedscount .... expect ...});

Comment: Still fails every now and then with this change nilsK

Comment: Maybe I should add that the checkbox controls are JQMobile

Comment: then it may have something to do with protractor not auto-magically waiting for angular :) i am afraid, this isn't new to you. you may need to use 'browser.driver' syntax, take a look at [non-angular protractor docs example] (https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/f52438549f7d920da1600199feaf58059d6fd692/spec/withLoginConf.js) but i am not experienced with protractor on non-angular sites

Comment: I didn't mean that it' s not angular. The checkboxes are actually generated by angular:
    <div data-ng-repeat="status in BedStatus">
                    <label for="checkbox-status-b{{$index}}">   {{getBedStatusText(status.Status)}} </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-status-b{{$index}}" data-ng-model='statusModel[status.Status]' data-ng-click="toggleStatusSelection(status.Status)" />
                </div>

Answer (score 1):

If the page is indeed an Angular page then **remove** this line:

> ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;

So Protractor can wait properly.

You don't need to `ptor = protractor.getInstance()` on latest versions of Protractor, just start using `browser` instead of `ptor`

I would also split the test steps instead of doing too much within one `it()` block. It helps with the logs and while debugging issues like *where does my tests break?*.

```
// TODO: Move to page object file
var mapElm = $('label[for="checkbox-status-all"]');
var chkElm = $('label[for="checkbox-status-b0"]');
var bedscountElm = $('#marker_10 span');

// A more general function to wait for elements on non-angular pages
function waitForElmPresent(elmFinder) {
    browser.wait(function() {
        return elmFinder.isPresent();
    }, 5000);
}

it('opens the test page', function() {
    browser.get(browser.params.testurl);
});

it('waits for the map', function() {
    // shouldn't be necessary with ignoreSyncronization is left alone
    waitForElmPresent(mapElm);
});

it('also waits for the checkbox before clicking', function() {
    // shouldn't be necessary with ignoreSyncronization is left alone
    waitForElmPresent(chkElm);
});

it('clicks the checkbox', function() {
    chkElm.click();
});

it('and also waits for the bubble to be present', function() {
    // shouldn't be necessary with ignoreSyncronization is left alone
    waitForElmPresent(bedscountElm);
});

it('expect 30 to be shown in bubble', function() {
    expect(bedscountElm.getText()).toEqual('30');
});
```